# Using sed, how can I remove lines with salaries ending 500?

Tags: linux, sed

Using sed, how can I remove lines with salaries ending 500?

Input file:

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245500
Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed '/500$/d' filename
```

Or with grep:

```
grep -v 500$ filename
```

The $ denotes end of line.  Also, the ^ character denotes the beginning of line. ^$ denotes a blank line.

Comment: Works great! Thank you jftuga for the explanations ...